# String replace for a column pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, replace, split

I have a data frame such as :

col1

```
OK.1:177788-1000(+):Genus_species
OK.1:177788-2000(+):Genus_species
OK.1:177788-3000(+):Genus_species
OK.1:177788-3000(+):Genus_species
```

And I would like to get :

```
OK.1_177788-1000_+__Genus_species
OK.1_177788-2000_+__Genus_species
OK.1_177788-3000_+__Genus_species
OK.1_177788-3000_+__Genus_species
```

instread but I do not really know how to do it in one line with re.sub for instance I tried:

```
df['col1'].replace(to_replace="\(", value=r"_", regex=True)
df['col1'].replace(to_replace="\)", value=r"_", regex=True)
df['col1'].replace(to_replace="\:", value=r"_", regex=True)
```

But I'm looking for something smarter in one line.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You might try a character class `[)(:]`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your dataframe is all strings, str.replace should do the trick with no regex needed.

```
df = df.col1.str.replace('(+):', '_+__', regex=False)
```

You set `regex = False` here to indicate that you are looking for these strings literal and not its regex representation.

Example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['OK.1:177788-1000(+):Genus_species', 'OK.1:177788-2000(+):Genus_species']})
```

Output:

```
                             col1
0  OK.1:177788-1000(+):Genus_species
1  OK.1:177788-2000(+):Genus_species
```

Then use

```
df = df.col1.str.replace('(+):', '_+__', regex=False)
```

Output:

```
                         col1
0    OK.1:177788-1000_+__Genus_species
1    OK.1:177788-2000_+__Genus_species
```

Answer (score 0):

This should fulfill your requirements:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['OK.1:177788-2000(+):Genus_species',
                         'OK.1:177788-3000(+):Genus_species',
                         'OK.1:177788-3000(+):Genus_species']})
df['b'] = df.a.str.replace(':|\(|\)', '_', regex=True)
print(df)
```

Gives:

```
                                   a                                  b
0  OK.1:177788-2000(+):Genus_species  OK.1_177788-2000_+__Genus_species
1  OK.1:177788-3000(+):Genus_species  OK.1_177788-3000_+__Genus_species
2  OK.1:177788-3000(+):Genus_species  OK.1_177788-3000_+__Genus_species
```